# SQL Query to get nearest previous and next date?

Tags: mysql

I've got a problem to combine SQL query that should show me nearest (previous and next) date from `CURDATE()`.

I've got table with customers and table witch events

Table with customers:

```
konto_odbiorcy | name
---------------+----------------
2              | Sony LTD
3              | Panasonic LTD
etc...
```

This is what I've got in table with events:

```
number | date 
-------+-------------
2      | 2016-11-01
2      | 2016-11-06
2      | 2016-11-14
3      | 2016-11-02
3      | 2016-11-21
3      | 2016-11-26
```

I need to know what is the last past date and next nearest future date like:

```
number | date past   | date future
-------+-------------+-------------
2      | 2016-11-06  | 2016-11-14
3      | 2016-11-02  | 2016-11-21
```

As you see, for `number=3` show me `2016-11-21` not `2016-11-26`

When I want show past nearest date:

```
SELECT number, date AS past
FROM 3ce_event
WHERE date <= CURDATE()
```

for next event:

```
SELECT number, date AS future
FROM 3ce_event
WHERE date >= CURDATE()
```

now how to compare this two with my customers table in one SQL query?

**EDIT**

I changed my query to **Mike** answer:

```
select 
    number, klienci_ax_all.nazwa, miasto,
    max(case when date<=curdate() then date end) as date_past,
    min(case when date>=curdate() then date end) as date_future
from 3ce_event
inner join klienci_ax_all on 3ce_event.number = klienci_ax_all.konto_odbiorcy
group by konto_odbiorcy
```

Looks really good, but I had problem with my customers table (`klienci_ax_all`). If for one or more customers there is nothing in `3ce_event` table, I don't have this customer as `Null` date_past and `Null` date_future.

I need full list of customers from `klienci_ax_all` then past and future data if exist... any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select number,
       max(case when date<=curdate() then date end) as date_past,
       min(case when date>=curdate() then date end) as date_future
  from event
 group by number
```

Comment: i edited my post... could You check that? i think i mess with JOIN option :(

Comment: @Triple_6 Change `INNER JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to self join to events generating subsets for min/max of each date for each group..

```
SELECT E.Number, E2.LTDate as `Date Past`, E1.GTDate as `Date Future`
FROM Events E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT number, min(date) GTDate 
           FROM events
           WHERE date >= CurDate 
           GROUP BY Number) E1
 on E.Number = E1.Number
LEFT JOIN (SELECT number, Max(date) LTDate 
           FROM events
           WHERE date <= CurDate 
           GROUP BY Number) E2
 on E.Number = E2.Number
```

Another way would be to use correlated inline queries (Select w/in the select) to find the min/max

```
SELECT E.Number
    , (Select max(E1.date) from events E1 where E1.Number = E.Number and E1.date<=sysdate)
    , (Select min(E1.date) from events E2 where E2.Number = E.Number and E2.date>=sysdate)
FROM Events E
```

I'm more of a fan for the 1st approach as it doesn't have to execute 3 queries for each record in the events table; however on a smaller dataset the 2nd may be faster.